# Same voltage, different amperage for two power supplies

Tags: laptop, power-supply, voltage

I've just plugged an 18.5V 6.4A HP power supply into an HP laptop; I normally use an 18.5V 3.5A power supply. Since the connector fit, I figured I'd give it a go... so far no funny smells or fires.

Is this setup doomed to failure or will all end well?

Unfortunately I've forgotten everything I learned in high school...

Answer (score 7):

This is fine. The amperage rating for a power supply indicates how much current it is able to provide. Your laptop won't draw that much current, so it won't damage anything.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds ok to me.  I've run HP's 90 watt adapter for several years on a laptop that came with the 65 watt adapter.  I wouldn't advise going the OTHER way, but as long as the power supply can supply more current than the laptop asks for it's no problem.